# How to hook/monkey-patch the basic Error class

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I go about "patching" (or replacing) the basic Error class, so that wherever anyone does `throw new Error()` in the code base (or tries to throw **anything that derives from Error**) what will actually be instantiated is some replacement class (that has some extra fields, logic).

I do realize this is far from being a best practice, and it's not meant for your typical JS development scenario, it's meant for some sandbox environment where arbitrary user-code gets run.

I tried something like this (which did not work):

```
OurError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
Error.prototype = OurError.prototype;
```

Clearly I don't know enough about prototypes to understand what I'm doing. Would appreciate some pointers or a simple example.

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `prorotype`

Comment: `window.Error = class OurError extends Error`. or `window.Error = OurError`.

Comment: should have mentioned this was a node.js question. added a tag.

Comment: node or browser, doesn't matter, just use proper global object.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that won't work for classes derived from Error. e.g. if someone does `throw new URIError()`

Comment: @AssafLavie I think that you cannot extend native JS.

Comment: @AssafLavie In browser you can use window.onerror - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Comment: Are you reading (and processing) the user input before executing it?

Comment: @cowCrazy no, I'm limited by how much of it I can process. The user may bring along npm packages, for example, and those may fire exceptions (derived from Error) that I want to be able to hook.

Answer (score 3):

You can always add more methods to the `Error.prototype`, and use them afterwards, like this (in ES6):

```
Error.prototype.hello = function() {
  console.log(`Hello from ${this.constructor.name}!`);
}

const a = new Error();
a.hello(); // outputs "Hello from Error"

class MyError extends Error {};

const b = new MyError();
b.hello(); // outputs "Hello from MyError"
```

You can also replace the Error class completely like this:

```
class ImprovedError {
  constructor() {
    console.log(`I am an ${this.constructor.name}!`);
  }
};

Error = ImprovedError;
const c = new Error(); // outputs "I am an ImprovedError"
```

Be aware that replacing the `Error` class completely might have some adverse consequences and unpredictable results when interacting with external dependencies (libraries) since they may expect and call the methods of the original `Error` class.

For more info on the `Error` class methods and behaviour [see here](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_error)